# install libdb-devel on centos 6

Tags: centos6, yum

I need to install libdb-devel on a Centos 6 to compile my program. I managed to find it [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/russian-fedora-free-updates-x86_64/libdb-devel-5.2.36-5.el6.R.x86_64.rpm.html), but I cannot install it as there is some conflict with an already installed db4-devel package

```
Transaction Check Error:
file /usr/include/db.h from install of libdb-devel-5.2.36-5.el6.R.x86_64 conflicts with file from package db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
file /usr/include/db_185.h from install of libdb-devel-5.2.36-5.el6.R.x86_64 conflicts with file from package db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
file /usr/include/db_cxx.h from install of libdb-devel-5.2.36-5.el6.R.x86_64 conflicts with file from package db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libdb.so from install of libdb-devel-5.2.36-5.el6.R.x86_64 conflicts with file from package db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
```

I cannot delete db4-devel because yum and others depends on it.
What can I do ?

Comment: What does `rpm -q --whatrequires db4-devel` return? yum doesn't need that package.

Comment: It returns `perl-devel` . Very curiously I can now uninstall db4-devel without conflict with yum. I am not sure what is going on and suspect I was very tired yesterday and made some stupid mistake somewhere.

Comment: Well it was still needed by redhat-lsb-core which I need  to use lsb_release in some of my scripts.  I'll need a workaround for that now. Another topic I guess

Comment: I've done it quick and dirty. I downloaded the rpm file for libdb-devel and installed it manualy with rpm -i --replacefiles. It seems to works and nothing broke for now.